# QuerySet.annotate() and .get() in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

In my database I have a table card linked to a table amount, 1 card can have many amounts.

So with django I try to get a specific card and aggregate the sum of all the amounts linked. But impossible to concatenate .get() and .annotate together.

I tried this:

```
    last_year_amount = Card.objects.get(date__date=date(today.year - 1, 
    today.month, today.day)).annotate(total=Sum(Amount.amount))
```

But of course it raises an error ''Card' object has no attribute 'annotate''.
I understand that .get() return an object an not a QuerySet so .annotate doesn't exists as a method of this object.

But how to get this object with the annotate?

Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 3):

Swap the order of `annotate` and `get`.

```
 last_year_amount = Card.objects\
   .annotate(total=Sum('amount'))\
   .get(date__date=date(today.year - 1, today.month, today.day))
```

You could also use a `filter()`.

```
 last_year_amount = Card.objects\
   .filter(date__date=date(today.year - 1, today.month, today.day))\
   .annotate(total=Sum('amount'))\
   .get()
```

The final `get()` with no arguments will raise an exception if the queryset doesn't contain exactly one item.

Answer (score 0):

I tried, but had another error.

Finally I had an error in the Amount.amount and in the format of get.

The solution was:

```
    last_year_amount = Card.objects.filter(date__date=date(today.year - 1, today.month, today.day)).annotate(total=Sum('amount__amount'))[:1].get()
```

Which works very fine

Answer (score 0):

How about going in the reverse order:

```
Amount.objects.filter(card__date__date=date(today.year - 1, today.month, today.day)).values('card').annotate(total=Sum('amount'))
```

I assumed that `Amount` model has a foreign key to `Card` model with field name of `card`.